# change location of variable in memory

Tags: assembly, masm

assume in the masm I defined a variable in data segment :

```
.data
AppName db "PE tutorial ",0
```

now in code section I defined several heaps :

```
invoke GetProcessHeap
mov hmyHeap,eax
invoke HeapAlloc,hmyHeap,HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,Memsize
mov heap1,eax
```

Now we have a memory location in heap and I want to change the memory location of AppName in data segment to this heap1 location . I don't want to copy the content! I want to change memory location

Comment: Changing memory location means exactly this - to copy the information from one place in memory to another place in memory.

Or your question is not clear enough?

Comment: You can't change the address of `AppName`, since it's been set when your program was linked. All you can do is copy it.

Comment: @johnfound I exactly want to change address of AppName , what  Michael say.

Comment: So, Michael have to write the proper answer and RF27 to accept it. :)

Comment: @johnfound he understand what I want but he does'n have any answer to it :)

Comment: @RF27 - what you want is actually impossible and that is the answer of your question. In addition, I would suggest you to read some books about assembly programming, but it is dangerous here - I will get bunch of down votes for such a suggestion. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. The name `AppData` will be translated into a fixed offset relative to the `.data` when you assemble your source file (possibly slightly simplified, but to get the point across, all instances of `AppData` will be replaced by `.data+0x0000001c`, for example).

Therefore, at runtime there is no name `AppData` anymore so that you could change its memory location.

Compare to C: What you want to do is basically

```
int AppData;
int b;
&AppData = &b;
```

which doesn't work in C either but will give `error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment`. The C solution would be to use a pointer:

```
int *AppData;
int b;
AppData = &b;
```

and similarly, you can do that in assembly.

```
AppName db "PE tutorial ",0
AppNamePtr dd ?
;in code, initialize the pointer to AppName's address
;then, when you allocate your heapmemory, change AppNamePtr.
```

Comment: @johnfound You are free to downvote whatever you like of course, but my answer has an explanation of why the OP's approach doesn't work *and* a suggestion how to make it work in assembly. The analogy to C is there merely as, well, an analogy. I'm not quite sure how this makes my answer "not useful" (which is the alt-text of the downvote button and the usual reason to downvote answers).

Comment: Well, it is not useful for me, because I don't know C. If the answer is useful for the OP, he can vote up or even accept it. :)